# Angular 9 app to Cordova android - component not loading properly on pressing back button

Tags: angular, cordova

I converted an angular 9 app to `Cordova` android. When I visit a different component from the main page and press the back button, the main page does not load properly. The same issue is happening for other components too.

config.xml :-

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <name>Covid tracker</name>
        <description>       
            App provides information about corona virus statistics
        </description>
        <author email="hkumar0132@gmail.com" href="http://cordova.io">
            Covid-tracker developer contact
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>
    </widget>
```

index.html :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Covid-19 tracker</title>
    <base href="./">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/AdminLTE.min.css">
  
</head>
  
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
  </body>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

angular.json :-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "covid-info": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "covid-info:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "covid-info:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "covid-info:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "covid-info:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "covid-info:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "covid-info",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

I understand it has something to do with mobile routing as mobile routing and web routing works differently.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you some more details and code to it.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot It's added. Please help.

Comment: script you are calling outside html. it should be part of header.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Thanks, that solved the problem :)

Comment: Glad. I added as answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script are outside of html that need to be part of header. Move it to head section.

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

That will resolve your issue.